# Avoid sliding animation of content when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following simple `slideToggle` in `jQuery` which you can also find in the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/20/) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel_button").on('click', function() {
    $(".panel").slideUp();
    var targetPanel = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(targetPanel).slideToggle(0);
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel_button {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

#panel1, #panel2, #panel3 {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents">

  <div id="panel1" class="panel">
    <div class="content_01a">Here goes content1a</div>
    <div class="content_01b">Here goes content1b</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel2" class="panel">
    <div class="content_02a">Here goes content2a</div>
    <div class="content_02b">Here goes content2b</div>
    <div class="content_02c">Here goes content2c</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
    <div class="content_03a">Here goes content3a</div>
    <div class="content_03b">Here goes content3b</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> Button_01 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel2"> Button_02 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel3"> Button_03 </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the code above I display/hide `contents` depending on the `button` which is pushed. 
 All this works fine so far.

---

However, I want to change the animation of the "incoming" content once the `button` is clicked. 
Right now when you click on a `button` the new `content` somehow is sliding in from below and covers the previous `content`. However, I just want that the `content` is switched **immediately** when the `button` is clicked without the "sliding". Therefore, I put `0` on the `slideToggle` but it does not work.

Do you have any idea what I need to change in my code to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hide()` instead of `slideUp()` and `show()` instead of `slideToggle()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel_button").on('click', function() {
    $(".panel").hide();
    var targetPanel = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(targetPanel).show();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel_button {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

#panel1, #panel2, #panel3 {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents">

  <div id="panel1" class="panel">
    <div class="content_01a">Here goes content1a</div>
    <div class="content_01b">Here goes content1b</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel2" class="panel">
    <div class="content_02a">Here goes content2a</div>
    <div class="content_02b">Here goes content2b</div>
    <div class="content_02c">Here goes content2c</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
    <div class="content_03a">Here goes content3a</div>
    <div class="content_03b">Here goes content3b</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> Button_01 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel2"> Button_02 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel3"> Button_03 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot for your answer. I also updated it here http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/21/

Comment: Yeah, I already wanted to but still have to wait a few minutes.